# Java Web Start 9 using older Java .war Main class not found

Tags: java, java-web-start, java-9

I am working on a product which got quite behind with the Java version (I use Java 6 to compile it). The product is split up in 3 maven projects. (1 of them has a dependency on the other 2)

In order to release this product I pack the Java 6 generated .jar files into .war files and deploy them on a server. The users run the program using Java Web Start which will check if the wars aforementioned have been updated or not.

The problem came up when trying to run this deployed project using JRE 9. The java console complains that the Main class of my project could not be found.
I tried to compile my project using Java 9 inside Netbeans and run it and it works like a charm.

This is the tree of the generated .war file:

`├── app [56 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── index.html
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── lib
    └── web.xml`

My question is: what could be the reason why java web start is unable to find the main class?

Comment: are you packaging your jars inside the war, or just converting the jars to wars?

Comment: unpack your war file and check if it has a manifest.mf

Comment: The jars are packed inside the war.
I updated the question with the structure of my war file.

Comment: can you check if your manifest has an attribute "main-class" and does it reference the right class

Comment: It does, I know this for a fact because it works when using an older version than Java 9